# What does ToolStripProfessionalRenderer.OnRenderItemBackground do?

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi, renderer, toolstrip

I am writing a custom [ToolStripProfessionalRenderer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripprofessionalrenderer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) component and currently working through all of the OnRender... overrides.

This one in particular has stumped me: [OnRenderItemBackground](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstriprenderer.onrenderitembackground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I can't see it drawing anything, so to force it to draw something I've done this:

```
protected override void OnRenderItemBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, e.Item.ContentRectangle);
}
```

...but I don't see any red rectangles, so not sure what it's doing!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the stock ToolStripItems you can add with the designer already render their own background.  So what you draw with your OnRenderItemBackground() override is immediately over-painted again.  So ProfessionalToolStripRender simply doesn't override the method since nothing needs to be done.  The base class method, ToolStripRender.OnRenderItemBackground(), doesn't do anything either.

Note OnRenderButtonBackground(), OnRenderDropDownButtonBackground(), OnRenderLabelBackground(), etcetera.